# prove that [$\frac{[x]}{c}$] = [$\frac{x}{c}$] where [.] belongs to greatest integer . and c is any natural number.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, solution-verification

how to prove this using basic methods ?

Comment: You can also try this converse.  If $c$ is not an integer, then $$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{c}\right\rfloor \ne \left\lfloor\frac{x}{c}\right\rfloor$$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\left[\frac xc\right]=n\\
n \le \frac xc < n+1\\
cn \le x < cn+c\end{align}$$

Since $cn$ is an integer, $x \ge cn \implies [x]\ge cn$.

We also have $[x] \le x < cn+c$.

Hence:

$$\begin{align}cn \le [x]< cn+c\\
n \le \frac{[x]}c< n+1\\
\left[\frac{[x]}c\right]=n
\end{align}$$